# TinyMCE API key for localhost

Tags: html, tinymce, api-key

I'd like to incorporate TinyMCE as an HTML editor for templated email content for an opensource emailing package I'm working on for my non-profit work.

I had envisioned the editor operating under "localhost" only.  When I went to register for a API key, the process implied I needed to register a domain.  While I feel I could keep using the editor with the "this isn't registered" message, I was hoping to remove that if possible.

Is there a way to utilize the API key while hosting the editor under localhost?

Answer (score 0):

The solution of how to remove the warning message is explained in the documents [which can be found here.](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/quick-start/#step3addyourapikey) But, using the TinyMCE with self-hosted version could be more responsive and there is no need to work with API keys. If you have enough time, I would suggest to use [self-hosted version of TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/advanced-install/#self-hostedinstall) for a better experience.